# Find maximum sum path through binary tree - javascript

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

I've been trying to figure this problem out for a couple days and can't seem to optimize the solution to make it tenable.

I have a tree that's 100 levels deep, so brute force (2^100 possible combinations?) is obviously not working..

Here is the code I have so far:

```
// Node constructor | structure of nodes
var Node = function(val) {
  this.val = Number(val);
  this.left = null;
  this.right = null;
}

function maxPathUtil(top, store) {
  if (top === null || top === undefined) return 0;
  if (top.left === null && top.right === null) {
    // console.log("hello");
    return top.val;
  }

  leftSub = maxPathUtil(top.left, store);
  rightSub = maxPathUtil(top.right, store);
  store[0] = Math.max(store[0], leftSub+rightSub+top.val);

  return Math.max(leftSub, rightSub) + top.val;
}

function maxPathSum(top) {
  store = [];
  store[0] = 0;
  maxPathUtil(top, store)
  return store[0];
}

var top = nodify(levels);
console.log(maxPathSum(top));
```

Is there a way to memoize this solution / otherwise improve the big O or is that as efficient as it gets?

Comment: So you're looking for the greatest sum of nunbers in a binary tree where every node has a number?

Comment: Yes, values of each node are also not in any particular order.

Comment: Can you change the part where you add the nodes to the tree and/or the nodes?

Comment: Yes, I'm parsing a text file to construct the tree (not shown) but it seems like altering the structure of the tree would change the max sum available.

Comment: I'm not changing the structure, I'm changing the way nodes behave

Comment: BTW, a 100 deep tree would be impossible, because it would take up at least  5 GBs

Answer (score 0):

So, each node should have ab additional extra property, let's call it "currLength"

When you parse the text file and you add the nodes to the tree, then you need to set the this value to the currLength of the parent node + the value of the current node.

After this you only need to check the bottom nodes of the tree to get the lengths of each path.

If you want to optimize this further, then you can add a currMaxLength variable to the tree, set it to -Infinity initially, and when you add a node with a higher currLength, then you set currMaxLength to currLength.

Keep in mind, this doesn't make it any faster, this just moves the compexity to the init part. It works like insertion sort.

Comment: So with this addition to the node structure, I would be able to solve a tree with depth of 100, or is that still too much complexity?

Comment: @pauld With this node structure it pretty much doesn't matter how deep your tree is. Though, you can't jave a tree with the depth of 100, that would require an insane amount of memory

Comment: This made me laugh a little.  Assuming the tree is balanced, this would be 2^100 which works out to 1.268*10^30 nodes.  By comparison, a quick google search shows there are an estimated 7.5*10^18 grains of sand in the world.

Answer (score 0):

here's how I've solved this problem in JavaScript, hope it helps!

```
var hasPathSum = function(root, sum) {
    if (root == null) {
        return false
    }
    var result = checkTree(root,root.val,sum)
    console.log(result)
    return result 
};

function checkTree(node,currentSum,sum) {
    if (currentSum == sum && node.left == null && node.right == null) {
        return true
    }
    var result = false
    if (node.left != null) {
        result = result || checkTree(node.left,currentSum+node.left.val,sum)
    }
    if (node.right != null) {
        result = result || checkTree(node.right,currentSum+node.right.val,sum)
    }
    return result
}
```

also on [my Github](https://github.com/dm20/Node-Structures/blob/master/Trees/BinaryTree/Helpers/BinaryTreePathSum.js)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function pathSum(root , sum){
      //Add Base Case For Recursion
      
      if(root === null)return false;
      
      //Add another base case 
      if(root.val === sum &&(root.left === null && root.right === null)return true
    
 // here when it reach to the leaf where the next is null for both left and right

      return pathSum(root.left , sum - root.val)|| pathSum(root.right ,sum - root.val )
      
      //So In the code above I added (||) because If the first recursion return false, it will execute next recursion and so on 
    }
```